# Partial Differential Equations, Separation of Variables of Heat Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I might need some help on this question:

Consider $\dfrac {\partial T}{\partial t} = k\cdot \left(\dfrac {\partial^2T}{\partial x^2}\right), 0\le x\le L$, where $k>0$ and $T(0,t)=T(L,t)=0$.

Solve for $T(x,t)$ w/ the following,

a). $T(x,0) = T_0 \sin\left(\dfrac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$

b). $T(x,0) = T_0 \cos\left(\dfrac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$

I got the idea of solving these equations for the separation constant. I just confused on when to initialize the initial conditions

Comment: Show your work.

Comment: @thanasissdr, Thank you for the editing

Comment: @SSivetts No problem! However, if you stick around here, I guess it would be useful to learn a bit of LaTeX writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using separation of variables, you will have two ODE's in terms of time and space, apply initial conditions T(x,0) to the time variant ODE and apply boundary conditions for space variant ODE.

[image]

[image]

In this $c^2 = \frac{1}{k}$

Put T(x,0) the intitial condition and equate

a) $$T(x,0) = b_nsin(\frac{n\pi x}{L}) = T_0sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$$

Leading to $$b_n = T_0$$

In part b)

$$T(x,0) = b_nsin(\frac{n\pi x}{L}) = T_0cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$$

Leading to $$b_n = T_0cot(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$$

Now $T(x,t) = X_n(t).T_n(t)$ in the both the parts.

Comment: Did you forget to add something next to "what I have is this"?

Comment: Yeah, this is what I am trying to type in: For lambda <=0, what I have for u(x,y) = SUM[B_n sin((n*pi*x)/L)(e^-((n*pi)/L)^2)(t))]     For the initial condition                                     u(x,0) = SUM[B_n sin((n*pi*x)/L)] = T_0 sin((n*pi*x)/L)             Sorry, this is my first time on this site.

Comment: Why K and not -K? Always wondered that in PDEs. People use K or -K accordingly but I never understood why the choose each one, and that minus sign really makes a huge difference.

Comment: @SSivetts, Look at the solution, the last steps indicate how you can apply initial conditions to get b_n. It is not the sum but just X_n or T_n

Comment: So choosing arbitrarily $k$ or $-k$ will yield the same result?

Comment: @UserX, the -K is sheer convenience of representing the eigenvalue I don't know of any physical meaning of why it should be -K over K

Comment: If you know why it should be, let me know! Thanks

Comment: I just started learning PDEs and Paul's online notes give a lot of attention on that minus sign on PDEs but the explanation is pretty vague. But it makes sense to me that solving the $-k$ ODE would yield a sinusoid function while solving the $k$ one would yield an exponential, which even if connected, are pretty different.

Comment: with k being positive, a second order differential equation would never give an exponential if I am not mistaken

Comment: Meant rational function sorry.

Comment: Okay @UserX aand satishramanathan, Thank you for all of your help, I really appreciate it

Comment: How do I do that on this site?

Comment: Click on the accept sign the tick mark.  Thanks